# how to format atom date time

Tags: php, parsing, datetime, atom-feed

I'm getting dates from feed in this format:

```
2009-11-04T19:55:41Z
```

I'm trying to format it using the `date()` function in PHP, but I get an error saying:

> date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given in /bla/bla.php

I tried using `preg_replace()` to remove the `T` and the `Z`, but still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`strtotime`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is a wonderful function for converting date formats to Unix timestamps.

This will give you what you're after:

```
date('my format here', strtotime('2009-11-04T19:55:41Z'));
```

Comment: Remember that `strtotime` uses the timezone it can find (for example in the `TZ` environment variable. The function documentation fails to give any pointers on what happens to timestamps that embed the time zone information.

Answer (score 13):

What about

```php
\DateTime::createFromFormat(\DateTime::ATOM, $AtomDate); // converting Atom date to object
```

or

```php
date(\DateTime::ATOM, $timestamp); // formatting timestamp to Atom time
```

or both

```php
$dto = \DateTime::createFromFormat(\DateTime::ATOM, $AtomDate);
date('d-M-Y H:i:s', $dto->getTimestamp()); // formatting Atom date to anything you want
```

or even better

```php
$dto = \DateTime::createFromFormat(\DateTime::ATOM, $AtomDate);
$formattedDate = $dto->format('d-M-Y H:i:s');
```

or with time zone (*as mentioned in comments*)

```php
$dto = \DateTime::createFromFormat(
    \DateTime::ATOM,
    $ticketUpdatedAt,
    new \DateTimeZone('UTC')
);
$ticketUpdatedDate = $dto->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Didn't knew this atom constant, useful !

Comment: With timezone                                                                                                         
      $dto = \DateTime::createFromFormat(\DateTime::ATOM, $ticketUpdatedAt, new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
        $ticketUpdatedDate = $dto->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`strptime`](http://uk.php.net/strptime):

```
$date = strptime($str, "Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [strtotime](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function.

```
echo date('Y-M-D', strtotime($feedDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the standard ISO 8601 combined date and time format given in UTC (hence the Z).

You might be able to parse it using

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('c', '2009-02-03');
```

or, if that fails (shouldn't, if PHP claims to understand ISO 8601), you can replace the Z by "+00:00".